# Getting certain key of returned JSON after using IMPORTDATA function

Tags: google-sheets

I am calling [this](https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/pricehistorical?fsym=ETH&tsyms=BTC,USD&ts=1452680400) url using the `=IMPORTDATA()` function and I am getting the following JSON back:

```
{"ETH":{"BTC":0.002616,"USD":1.13}}
```

How can I visualize only the value of the USD key in the cell?

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there is an easier way, but this will do it:

```
=index(split(substitute(index(importData("https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/pricehistorical?fsym=ETH&tsyms=BTC,USD&ts=1452680400"),0,2),"}}",""),":"),0,2)
```